# How to disable Right Click on Ifram Pdf file

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, iframe

Please Any one can help me for solving this problem.I want to my web page show pdf file using Ifram, but i want just disable right click on ifram.
My Code is Bellow

```js
$(document).contextmenu(function () {
                                return false;
                            });
```

```html
<iframe id="pdf"   src="<?= base_url('assets/uploads/' . $notice['file']); ?>#toolbar=0&scrollbar=0&navpanes=0&embedded=true&statusbar=0&view=Fit;readonly=true;disableprint=true;" 
                            style="width:100%; height:900px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: It's a plug-in showing the PDF, you probably can't access that plug-in.

Comment: Why don't you want people to be able to right click on it? If the PDF is loaded in the iframe, it's already downloaded to the users computer so they can always access it either way.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this in javascript

```
<script language="javascript">
document.onmousedown=disableclick;
status="Right Click Disabled";
Function disableclick(e)
{
  if(event.button==2)
   {
     alert(status);
     return false;  
   }
}
</script>
```

But anyways any Javascript you code can be rendered mute by simply turning off Javascript on the browser.

Additionally, there's no way to disable the ability of any user to simply "view source" or "view page info" for your site and get what they want.

Hope the code helps you, and you reconsider disabling right click.

One more way in JS :

```
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Also, your code looks like JQuery, so here's JQuery example :

```
$(function() {
    $(this).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```